# Android - sqlite - createdAt and updatedAt - events?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am newbie in Android. Now I create SQLite database and I would like create fields createdAt and updatedAt. 
In others languages and frameworks is possible to automatically add createdAt and updatedAt fields. I know - in SQLite there is no date column so better create own this function, but if I have for example insert data to one table in Activity and Fragment, then can I automatically updated field updatedAt?

How is the best and easiest way for this?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Write your own helper functions for creating and updating stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are no specific column types for Date/Time SQLite does have Date/Time functions. This along with column types being flexible makes it relatively simple to have columns for dates.

For example if you used the following as the SQL to create a table :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
  _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  created TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
  updated TEXT, 
  mydata TEXT
)
```

The when a new row is added the **`created`** column will be set with the current date time.

e.g. it's value would be along the lines of **`2017-10-07 20:37:51`**

You could use the following sql to update the **`updated`** column :-

```
UPDATE mytable SET updated = DATETIME('NOW') WHERE _id = id_of_row_to_be_updated.
```

You may find [SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) interesting and or useful.

Alternately you could use timestamps e.g. by storing System.currentTimeMillis();

The following is code, that uses both methods columns **`created`** and **`updated`** being used for storing the values as strings and **`altcrtd`** and **`altupdtd`** for timestamps :-

#### The DBHelper (SQLiteOpenHelper subclass) :-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "logging";
    public static final String TBNAME = "log";
    public static final String CREATED_COL = "created";
    public static final String ALTCREATED_COL = "altcrtd";
    public static final String UPDATED_COL = "updated";
    public static final String ALTUPDATED_COL = "altupdtd";
    public static final String MYDATA_COL = "mydata";
    public static final String ID_COL = "_id";

    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        String tblcrt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBNAME + "(" +
                ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                CREATED_COL + " TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " +
                UPDATED_COL + " TEXT, " +
                ALTCREATED_COL + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
                ALTUPDATED_COL + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " +
                MYDATA_COL + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(tblcrt);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public void insertLogRow(String mydata) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(MYDATA_COL,mydata);
        cv.put(ALTCREATED_COL,Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        mDB.insert(TBNAME,null,cv);
    }

    public void updateLogRow(Long id, String mydate) {

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        if ((mydate != null) && (mydate.length() > 0)) {
            cv.put(MYDATA_COL,mydate);
        }
        cv.put(ALTUPDATED_COL,Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        mDB.update(TBNAME,cv,ID_COL + "=?",new String[]{Long.toString(id)});
        String sql = "UPDATE " + TBNAME +
                " SET " + UPDATED_COL + " = DATETIME('NOW') WHERE " +
                ID_COL + " = " + Long.toString(id);
        mDB.execSQL(sql);
    }

    public void displayAllRowsToLog() {
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBNAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            String displaydata = "Row - " + Integer.toString(csr.getPosition() + 1) +
                    " \n\tCREATED ON " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(CREATED_COL)) + " (TEXT)" +
                    " \n\tALTCRTD ON " + Long.toString(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(ALTCREATED_COL))) + " (LONG)" +
                    " \n\tUPDATED ON " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(UPDATED_COL)) + " (TEXT)" +
                    "\n\tALTUPDTD ON " + Long.toString(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(ALTUPDATED_COL))) + " (LONG)";
            Log.d("DBINFO",displaydata);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Useage with an Activcity (MainActivity in this case) :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get an instance of the DBHelper
        DBHelper dbhlpr = new DBHelper(this);

        // Insert some rows
        dbhlpr.insertLogRow("FIRST");
        dbhlpr.insertLogRow("SECOND");
        dbhlpr.insertLogRow("THIRD");

        // Display the current values
        dbhlpr.displayAllRowsToLog();

        // Update some rows (including a non-existant row)
        dbhlpr.updateLogRow(1L,"FIRST MODIFIED");
        dbhlpr.updateLogRow(20L,"No SUCH ROW"); // will do nothing as row doesn't exist
        dbhlpr.updateLogRow(3L,"THIRD MODIFIED");

        // Display the update rows
        dbhlpr.displayAllRowsToLog();
    }
}
```

#### The resultant output (first run)

```
10-08 08:16:16.997 7461-7461/mjt.so46619595_createdupdateddatetime D/DBINFO: Row - 1 
                                                                                CREATED ON 2017-10-07 21:16:16 (TEXT) 
                                                                                ALTCRTD ON 1507410976988 (LONG) 
                                                                                UPDATED ON null (TEXT)
                                                                                ALTUPDTD ON 0 (LONG)
10-08 08:16:16.997 7461-7461/mjt.so46619595_createdupdateddatetime D/DBINFO: Row - 2 
                                                                                CREATED ON 2017-10-07 21:16:16 (TEXT) 
                                                                                ALTCRTD ON 1507410976991 (LONG) 
                                                                                UPDATED ON null (TEXT)
                                                                                ALTUPDTD ON 0 (LONG)
10-08 08:16:16.997 7461-7461/mjt.so46619595_createdupdateddatetime D/DBINFO: Row - 3 
                                                                                CREATED ON 2017-10-07 21:16:16 (TEXT) 
                                                                                ALTCRTD ON 1507410976994 (LONG) 
                                                                                UPDATED ON null (TEXT)
                                                                                ALTUPDTD ON 0 (LONG)
10-08 08:16:17.011 7461-7461/mjt.so46619595_createdupdateddatetime D/DBINFO: Row - 1 
                                                                                CREATED ON 2017-10-07 21:16:16 (TEXT) 
                                                                                ALTCRTD ON 1507410976988 (LONG) 
                                                                                UPDATED ON 2017-10-07 21:16:17 (TEXT)
                                                                                ALTUPDTD ON 1507410976997 (LONG)
10-08 08:16:17.011 7461-7461/mjt.so46619595_createdupdateddatetime D/DBINFO: Row - 2 
                                                                                CREATED ON 2017-10-07 21:16:16 (TEXT) 
                                                                                ALTCRTD ON 1507410976991 (LONG) 
                                                                                UPDATED ON null (TEXT)
                                                                                ALTUPDTD ON 0 (LONG)
10-08 08:16:17.011 7461-7461/mjt.so46619595_createdupdateddatetime D/DBINFO: Row - 3 
                                                                                CREATED ON 2017-10-07 21:16:16 (TEXT) 
                                                                                ALTCRTD ON 1507410976994 (LONG) 
                                                                                UPDATED ON 2017-10-07 21:16:17 (TEXT)
                                                                                ALTUPDTD ON 1507410977004 (LONG)
```

**`updateLogRow`** could be invoked from within a fragment, you'd likely have to precede this by getting an instance of the **`DBHelper`** within the fragment.